# How to generate a list using a userform with Macros in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
        1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Tabla con cuadrícula" Then
            .Style = "Tabla con cuadrícula"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
    End With
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Título3"
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
```

That's the code I´m using. The first part creates the table just fine. But then the bookmark doesn't add to the table. I´m actually using the macro recorder for this, so I don´t know if there is some command I'm missing

Comment: Please edit your post to share what's your expected output in Word. I've tested your code w/o issues on Word 365.